# Azure Function how to convert JSON to Excel and save it to blob storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I was wondering, how can I save generated Excel file into blob storage when running this js code.please, do you have an idea how to preform something similar like fs.safeFileSync?

```
const fs = require('fs');
var json2xls = require('json2xls');
var json = {
    foo: 'bar',
    qux: 'moo',
    poo: 123,
    stux: "tester"
}

var pole = [];

pole.push(json);
pole.push(json);
pole.push(json);
pole.push(json);

var xls = json2xls(pole);

console.log("done, saved", xls);
fs.writeFileSync('data.xlsx', xls, 'binary'); //this saves file to disk, but I need to save it to a blob storage with the function below
context.bindings.outputBlob = ??????
```

Comment: Have you tried passing `xls` variable to `context.bindings.outputBlob`?

Comment: yes, I have. it did pass the file, but it says, file is corrupted

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is interested, I solved it like this:

```
const csval = require("csval");
var json2xls = require('json2xls');
var fs = require('fs');
const { BlobServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');
const AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = process.env.storageCred;

module.exports = async function (context, myQueueItem) {

    context.log('JavaScript queue trigger function processed work item', myQueueItem);
    const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING);

    var json = {
        foo: 'bar',
        qux: 'moo',
        poo: 123,
        stux: new Date()
    }


    var arry = [];
    arry.push(json);
    arry.push(json);

    var xls = json2xls(arry); 
    const data = Buffer.from(xls,'binary')
    const blobName = "excelfile.xls";
 

    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient("incontainer");
    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
    const uploadBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.upload(data, data.length);

    context.log("done")
};
```